# Using $this in Zend Model

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm trying to write `getFunction()` in my Zend Model

Only works:

```
public function getFunction($id){
    $Wiadomosc = new Application_Model_DbTable_Wiadomosc();
    $nieodczytane = $Wiadomosc->select();
    $nieodczytane->from(etc.....)
}
```

But i don't want to create object model in model!

I would like to do it in that way:

```
public function getFunction($id){
    $nieodczytane = $this->select();
    $nieodczytane->from(etc.....)
}
```

but..
`Method "select" does not exist and was not trapped in __call()`

how to do it?

Comment: Where are you calling this function getFunction($id), is it in the Wiadomosc class or not. Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

As I know select() function is defined in Zend Model Structure already, which your model inherited from, so make it like this:

```
public function getFunction($id){
  $nieodczytane = parent::select();
  $nieodczytane->from(etc.....)
}
```

Comment: Good idea but:
 Argument 1 passed to Zend_Db_Table_Select::__construct() must be an instance of Zend_Db_Table_Abstract, instance of SprzedawcaController given

Answer (score 0):

Although you question is well written and not easy to understand what you want to achieve by this. let me try to answer it.
If you are using the Zend DbTable. Let me try to explain how it works.

For Example you have the following model
//this class represents the table'Wiadomosc' in your Database scheme

class Wiadomosc{

```
protected $_name = 'Wiadomosc';
protected $_primary = 'id';
```

}
If you want write a get function regarding the model, normally you query by id and you 
fetch the row you want get, 
 you do as it in the Zend Framework way.

```
  /*** Get list. 
     * @param Integer $id
     * @return Array
     * @throws Exception if id could not be found.
     */
public function  getFunction($id)
{
    $id = (int)$id; //typcast 
    $row = $this->fetchRow('id = ' .$id);
    if(!$row)
    {
        throw new Exception("Could not find $id");
    }
    return $row->toArray();
}
```

If that is not the case and your querying from another modal you could try the following.

```
public function getFunction($id)
{

$select = $this->select();

$select->from(array('w' => 'Wiadomosc'), array('column1','column2', 'column3'));


$select->setIntegrityCheck(false);

if($rows = $this->fetchAll($select)){

    return $rows;
}elseif (empty($rows)){
    $rows = $this->_name->select();
    return $rows;
}

}
```

Edited:

You can do one of the following options:

```
 public function getFunction($id){

            $nieodczytane = $this->select();
            $nieodczytane->from(array('t' => 'YourTableName'),array('*'));

            if($rows = $this->fetchAll($nieodczytane)){
                return $rows;
            }
        }




    public function getFunction($id){

            $nieodczytane = $this->select();

            if($rows = $this->fetchAll($nieodczytane)){
                return $rows;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm trying to get function working with the same model so case 1.

but when i use $this->select()

Method "select" does not exist and was not trapped in __call()